# What is this translation of "Journey To The West"?

Tags: literature

I found this English translation of: [Journey To The West](http://www.innerjourneytothewest.com/english/books/JTW/) on [Inner Journey To The West](http://www.innerjourneytothewest.com/) dot com.

I can't see any information about the translation though.

Who did it?

Was it published?

Is it in the public domain?

Their main page doesn't say anything (that I can see) as regard to the translation itself.

---

edit: is it just Walther Sell himself?

the copyright at the bottom writes:

> © copyright 2009 - 2017 Walther Sell

and there is a [new abridged version](http://www.innerjourneytothewest.com/english/en-book.html)

[image: ed]

> edited by Walther Sell

Comment: Select some phrase from the book, long enough that different translators would probably express it different ways.  Search that phrase on Google.  You will probably find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Good Reads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17575278-journey-to-the-west), the book's authorship is listed as:

> by Wu Cheng'en, W.J.F. Jenner (Translator), Walther Sell (Editor)

W.J.F. Jenner is [William John Francis Jenner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_John_Francis_Jenner). His translation is [one of three notable English translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West#Notable_English-language_translations) done on the work.